# If a stochastic process conditioned on its endpoint values follows an SDE, does the marginal process also follow an SDE?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose we are given a stochastic process $X: [0, T] \to \mathbb{R}^D$ where $(X(0), X(T)) \in \mathbb{R}^{2D}$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma$. Suppose we are also given that conditionally on $(X(0), X(T))$, $X$ evolves according to the SDE:
$$dX_t = f(X_t, t; X_T) dt + L dW_t$$
where $X_T \equiv X(T)$, $W_t$ is a standard $D$-dimensional Brownian motion, and $L \in \mathbb{R}^{D\times D}$.

My question is whether we can say the unconditional process (integrating out the dependence on $(X(0), X(T))$) evolves according to some SDE as well, and if so, what the drift term of this SDE would be. It would be great, for instance, if the drift of the SDE describing the unconditional process was:
$$\tilde{f}(x, t) = \mathbb{E}[f(x, t; X_T)]$$

A proof or references would be appreciated. Feel free to assume smoothness or nice conditions on $f$. Please let me know if anything is unclear or if my terminology is off, as I am new to this area.

Comment: If only $X_T$ was fixed your first equation looks like a Backward SDE, see for example this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228388782_Backward_stochastic_differential_equations_and_applications) by El Karoui. However, the fact that $f$ depends on $X_T$ seems to me to be a bit problematic as $fdt$ does not seem adapted which could create some technical problems. Also what you mean by the marginal process is not clear to me. Do you the process if we were to integrate out the dependence on $\left(X(0), X(T)\right)$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Shiva. I will take a look at the article you linked. By the marginal process, I indeed meant to refer to the process where the dependence on $(X(0), X(T))$ is integrated out. I edited the question to make this clearer.

I mean to describe a process which can be generated by first sampling $(X(0), X(T))$ from a normal distribution, then sampling the trajectory between the endpoints by solving a SDE whose drift depends on the right endpoint $X(T)$. I think this will avoid the technical problems around adaptedness.

Comment: So I did a bit more digging and what you asked about seems more like something called a [diffusion bridge](https://mathoverflow.net/a/247597) or a conditioned diffusion. See the references in the post. After a cursory reading, I think the idea is to construct an SPDE on the space of continuous paths whose stationary measure coincides with the distribution of the solutions of your sde conditioned on them starting and terminating at the prescribed values. For $(X(0), X(T)) = (x_0,x_1)$, call this stationary measure $\mu_{x_0, x_1}$. It seems to me that you have generated a family of measures...

Comment: ... $ \left\{\mu_{x_0,x_1}\right\}_{x_0, x_1 \in \mathbb{R}}$ on $C :=C\left(\left[0,T\right], \mathbb{R}^D\right)$. So it seems to me that what you are trying to check is that for any continuous bounded $F:C \to \mathbb{R}$, $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{C} F(x) \mu_{x_0, x_1}(dx)\phi_{\mu, \Sigma}(dx_1) = \int_{C} F(x) \tilde{\mu}_{x_0}(dx),$$
where $\tilde{\mu}_{x_0}$ is the law of the solution of 
$$d\tilde{X}_t = \tilde{f}(t, X_t)dt + LdW_t, \quad X_0 = x_0$$ and $\phi_{\mu, \Sigma}$ a gaussian. I have no clue about how difficult this would be nor even if what I've said is well defined.